# ASP.NET MVC 3: get all textbox data from a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, textbox

I'm trying to get all the data that is submitted into textboxes at a view back to a controller so i can save the data to the database.

Some background information:
Teacher Task Quotation setup

The first view that the teacher sees are all the tasks he has given (dropdown). He can chose one of those tasks and click submit then he gets a view back where he can quote the students that submitted there tasks before the deadline.

So for each student he can change the points if he made a mistake or quote the task.
After that is done there are some points that need to be submitted. What i want to know is how i get all those points back (that are in the textboxes) from the form so i can easily submit them to the DB.

**Edit:** 
It seems that my question is kinda hard to understand so i made a little sketch of the current situation and the problem - you can view it here - http://i43.tinypic.com/xap54m.jpg

Possible problems: i allready use a viewmodel to require the submission of a task. 
Is it possible to have to viewmodels in a view?

Comment: So you basically have a form and you need to persist the data in the form to the db?

Comment: basically i got a bunch of textboxes at a view where i need the data from and put it into a db. The main question is how i get all the data that are in the textboxes back to my controller

Answer (score 0):

This is a really basic MVC question. You should probably read the MVC music store tutorial/pdf or the Nerd Dinner tutorial as both will show how to save/insert to the database using Entity framework.

I'llpost some code a little later.

Answer (score 0):

Use another viewmodel. To use two viewmodels in one view, either bind them together in a model class or use a tuple in a view like this:

```
@model Tuple<model1, model2>
```

Then you access it like this.

```
Model.Item1.Something and Model.Item2.Something
```

Comment: so what you propose is using @model Tuple<model1, model2> in the beginning of my view so i can use both viewmodels in a view and then when i submitted it what do i use as parameter at the ActionResult method?

Comment: Actually I don't know why would you like to have two models. Just use one, model with all the fields, and then your controller ActionResult method: `public ActionResult Contact(ModelView view){}`. To use your fields just do `view.something`